# c# Efficient algorithm to find a combination, which summation is equal to two known number, in two set of number

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let's say there are three sets of numbers

> A
>   1,2
>
> B
>   3,4
>
> C
>   5,6

The result 
`8,10`
The number near the result

I want to find out which one is can equal to a known set number. We can find out that B+C = result. Actually I found some algorithm method for a single number but what I need is multiple numbers. And I totally have no clue how to do it.

I am wondering whether there is any efficient algorithm to find out such combination.

I try with below code with single number. But totally no idea how to do double set number.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCombinations(int[] set, int sum, string values) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < set.Length; i++) 
    {
        int left = sum - set[i];
        string vals = set[i] + "," + values;

        if (left == 0) {
            yield return vals;
        } 
        else {
          int[] possible = set.Take(i).Where(n => n <= sum).ToArray();
          if (possible.Length > 0) {
              foreach (string s in GetCombinations(possible, left, vals)) {
                  yield return s;
              }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone. Forgive me for poor english.

Comment: This site is not to provide you with solutions. You have to try yourself. What did you tried?

Comment: What if you had the result `8,10` and in the list you had `5,2`, `3,8`, `7,5` and `3,5`?

Comment: "Actually i got found some algorithm method of single number " would you care to share it, that would be a starting point

Comment: I already have the result of 8,10.

But i want to find the group can archieve my goal.
For example , answer is B+C= 8,10

Comment: @RichardChua I know you already have the result, I was asking what happens in the situation where two groups satisfy the criteria

Comment: Is the combination only about two items?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the combination exists? If not what is *penalty function*? E.g. when `8, 10` is required, but the best we can achieve are `7, 9` and `9, 9`, what is the right answer then?

Comment: Can numbers be negative? Can we add up more than two items? Can we just take a single item (imagine, that we just have `D 8, 10`)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko , The answer can be both 7,9 and 9,9. And the number cannot be negative.

Comment: yes, we also can take a single item D 8,10

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, yes yes only two item

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre , sorry ya.. i did not understand what your question... I just need know is which one can get the result.  I need get the B and C

Comment: @RichardChua right... that still answers nothing. What if B, C, D and E all work